# Galois extension over (commutative) rings

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-cohomology

I was reading a paper by Childs, Garfinkel and Orzech and at some point they mentioned Galois extensions over commutative rings. I have never heard of this so I decided to look at one of the references. This brought me to the paper "A Cohomological Description of Abelian Galois Extensions" by Orzech himself. In this paper he writes the following:

Let $G$ be a group and $R$ a ring. We define a category $_{G}\mathcal{A}_R$ whose objects are $R$-algebras which are also $R(G)$-modules such that $G$ acts by $R$-algebra automorphisms. Here $R(G)$ denotes the group ring. The morphisms in this category are $R(G)$-module maps which are also $R$-algebra morphisms.

Let $A\in \ _{G}\mathcal{A}_R$. We define $e_G(A):=\left\{f:G\rightarrow A\mid \text{ $f$ is a function}\right\}$. We can turn $e_G(A)$ into a $R$-algebra under pointwise operations.

Consider the **morphism** $h:A\otimes A\rightarrow e_G(A)$ defined by $h(a\otimes b)(x):=ax(b)$ for all $a,b\in A$ and $x\in G$. We also define the $G$-coinvariants $A^G:=\left\{a\in A\mid x(a)=a, \forall x\in G\right\}$.

> We say that $A$ is a Galois extension of $R$ with group $G$ if $h$ is a bijection and $A^G=R$.

I have two questions concerning the above:

- What kind of morphism is $h$? The following calculation suggests that $h$ is **not** an algebra morphism. 
  \begin{eqnarray}
  h((a\otimes b)(c\otimes d))(x)&=& h(ac\otimes bd)(x)\\
  &=& acx(bd)\\
  &=& acx(b)x(d),\\
  (h(a\otimes b)h(c\otimes d))(x)&=& h(a\otimes b)(x)h(c\otimes d)(x)\\
  &=& ax(b)cx(d).
  \end{eqnarray}
- Secondly, I was wondering how this definition reduces to ordinary Galois extensions for fields. Suppose that $R$ is a field and $R\subset A$ is a field extension. Assume that $A$ is a Galois extension of $R$ with Galois group $G$ (as defined above). Then $A^G=R$ says that for any $x\in G$, the automorphism $x$ on $A$ restricted to $R$ is the identity. Hence $x\in \text{Gal}(A,R)$ where $\text{Gal}(A,R)$ is the ordinary Galois group of the field extension $R\subset A$. This does **not** imply that $G\subset \text{Gal}(A,R)$, indeed suppose that each $x$ acts trivially on $A$, then we may only conclude that $Id_A\in \text{Gal}(A,R)$. (There is a difference between the group $G$ and the group $G$ of automorphisms on $A$ with composition as multiplication). The fact that $h$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces(?) implies that $\dim(A)^2=\dim(e_G(A))$. However I can only show that $\dim(e_G(A))\geq \dim(A)$. So this is not to useful.

So how should I interpret this and why is it called a Galois extension?

Comment: I would try something like this :  "Let $K/F$ be a finite field extension and $H$ a subgroup of $Aut(K/F)$. Then $K^H$ the fixed field of $H$ contains $F$, and $K^H = F$ iff $H = Aut(K/F)$ and $K/F$ is Galois." (see the [characterization of Galois extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension))

Comment: I'm well aware of many equivalent characterizations of Galois extensions of fields, but that doesn't seem to provide an answer to my question. I have to link the group $G$ to the ordinary Galois group but this doesn't seem to work as I explained above, but I might be missing something.

Comment: I don't follow every detail of the construction. Don't you have a (finite) field extension $K/F$ such that $F$ is the fixed field of some subgroup $H \le Aut(K/F)$, therefore $K/F$ is Galois ?

Comment: @user1952009: I don't see how. As I ask it I don't have field extensions. I'm asking how to above definitions reduce to ordinary Galois extensions in case the structures involved are fields.

Comment: What ? In your last paragraph you wrote that $R \subset A$ is a field extension. $A^G = R$ means that $R$ is the fixed field of $G$. As I mentioned, this implies that $A/R$ is Galois (at least if $A/R$ is a finite extension)

Comment: I explicitly mentioned that the above definitions do not imply that $G\subset \text{Gal}(A,R)$. It's more subtle than that.

Comment: I don't see why. You said $G$ is a group of $R$-algebra automorphisms of $A$.

Comment: I don't say that $G$ is a group of $R$-algebra automorphisms. I say that $G$ is a group and $A$ is a $R(G)$-module such that elements of $G$ act as algebra automorphisms. Maybe the author means that $G$ is a group of algebra automorphisms, but that's not how it's written down, right?

Probably I'm making a mistake here, but to me $A$ could be a trivial $R(G)$-module, i.e. all elements of $G$ could act as the identity map.

Comment: @user1952009: After reading more on Galois extensions of commutative rings I found that they always define $G$ to be a group of automorphisms. This was not clear to me from the article (and also not written down this way). This also means that defining the category $_{G}\mathcal{A}_R$ is subtle. The objects are $R$-algebras whose group of automorphisms contains the group $G$ as a subgroup and then are $R(G)$-modules as well.

Assuming this definition, my second question is solved, but the first one still is a mistery.